# "this" does not work in my program

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

So basically, I'm doing an assignment on a game, and I'm trying to create the key commands. The only thing that does not work so far is the `addKeyListener(**this**)`.I tried fixing it but it ended up breaking my entire program. My code so far is:

```
public static void main (String[] args)
    throws InterruptedException {
    for (int x = 0 ; x < 999 ; x++)
    {
        int lvl = 0;
        int line = 0;
        write ();
        line = start (line);
        for (int p = 0 ; p < 999 ; p++)
        {
            if (line == 0)
            {
                System.out.println ("Select a level (1-3)");
                lvl = In.getInt ();
                if (lvl == 1)
                {
                    JFrame gamu = new JFrame ("Hoops 1.0");                        //JFrame that runs a game in a window
                    Culminating_MingxuanHe ball = new Culminating_MingxuanHe ();
                    gamu.getContentPane ().add (ball);
                    gamu.setSize (400, 480);       //sets the size for the game
                    gamu.setVisible (true);
                    ball.addKeyListener (this);
                    gamu.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);   //closes program when game is closed
                    while (true)
                    {
                        ball.moveBall ();       //runs the methods
                        ball.repaint ();
                        Thread.sleep (8);     //speed of the square
                    }
                }
                }
        }
        if (line == 1)
        {
            System.out.println ("Goodbye, have a nice day");
            x = 999;
        }
    }
}


int a = 200, s = 1, d = 100, f = 1;     //initial position of the square
int q = 150, w = 430, e = 80, r = 10;
int plat = 149;
int plat2 = 81;
int mov = 10;

public void moveBall ()
{
    if (a + s < 0)      //border on left
        s = 1;
    if (a + s > getWidth () - 25)      //border on right
        s = -1;
    if (d + f < 0)         //border on top
        f = 1;
    if (d + f > getHeight () - 25)  //border on bottom
        f = -1;
    a = a + s;           //moves the ball
    d = d + f;
}

public void KeyboardExample ()
{
    KeyListener listener = new keyPressed ();
    addKeyListener (listener);
    setFocusable (true);
}


public void keyPressed (KeyEvent e)
{
    int key = e.getKeyCode ();
    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
    {
        plat = plat - mov;
    }
    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
    {
        plat = plat + mov;
    }
}


public void keyTyped (KeyEvent e)
{
}


public void keyReleased (KeyEvent e)
{
}
```

}

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza  See [Detection/fix for the hanging close bracket of a code block](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251795/155831) for a problem I could no longer be bothered fixing.

Comment: A shorter example with your problem?

Comment: @AndrewThompson incomplete code is incomplete :(

Comment: What actually should `this` point to in a `static` function?

Comment: I'm not sure I just started Java this year. But the error says that "A "this" expression may only be used in a body of an instance method"

Comment: how does this program even work.. KeyListener listener = new keyPressed ();
    addKeyListener (listener); new keyPressed() how did you just make an instance of a method keyPressed() ?

Comment: Exactly. A `static` function has no instance, but just the class object. `this` always points to the current instance. Hence `this` does not make any sense in a static function.

Comment: Oh true. I didn`t realize the keyPressed wasn`t working either

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access the instance of an object. You can't do that, because the main method is static. Static methods are part of the CLASS, and instance methods are part of the OBJECT. What you are doing in your code is trying to access the object that you used to call main (i.e. variable.main), but it doesn't work because there is no object. Hopefully this helped :)